# Convergence of the series $2^{1/n} + 2^{-1/n} - 2$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have the following series:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(2^{\frac{1}{n}} + 2^{-\frac{1}{n}} - 2 \right)
$$
and want to prove it's convergence/divergence.

My intuition says it's convergent, because it's terms $a_n$ can be written as
$$
a_n = \left(2^{\frac{1}{n}} -1\right) + \left(2^{-\frac{1}{n}} -1 \right),
$$
and as $n \to \infty$, I can use the facts that
$$
2^\frac{1}{n}-1 \sim \frac{1}{n}\ln2, \\
2^{-\frac{1}{n}} -1 \sim -\frac{1}{n}\ln2
$$
so basically, for large $n$, I am looking at difference between two very similar series. However, I struggle to show that the rate at which this difference goes to zero is enough for this series to be convergent. I feel like limit comparison test with some clever convergent series could do the trick, but I can't choose such series. Choosing $b_n = 1/2^n$ or $b_n = 1/n^2$ seems to be inconclusive. So, how can I proceed?

Thank you.

Comment: **Hint:** For $y>0,$ $$y+1/y-2=\left(y^{1/2}-y^{-1/2}\right)^2,$$ so use $y=2^{1/n}.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $e^x + e^{-x} - 2 = x^2 + \frac{x^4}{12} + \frac{x^6}{360} + \cdots + \frac{2 x^{2n}}{(2n)!} + \cdots.$

It's easy to show that this series has a bound of the form $e^x + e^{-x} - 2 < kx^2$, where $k$ is some positive constant, for all $x$ sufficiently small. We could use the Taylor remainder theorem or, more simply, just compare the series to the clearly greater geometric series $x^2 + x^4 + x^6 + x^8 + \cdots = \frac{x^2}{1 - x^2}$, which gives us the bound (for example) $e^x + e^{-x} - 2 < \frac{4}{3} x^2$ valid for $|x| < \frac{1}{2}$.

Your sum is just adding the values of this expression at $x = \frac{\ln 2}{n}$, so it has the same convergence properties as $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$, which converges.